# Error logging in with Google. 12501 null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am switching from a Firebase Email/Password setup to a Google Sign in setup. The Email/Password setup worked fine, only now is it causing problems.

I am using FirebaseUI and am using verbatim their method for signing in with Google. I have done extensive googling and Stack Overflow research, and have double checked my SHA1 keys (both debug and release are on my Firebase), have kept my google-services.json file up to date, and I have the Google Services 3.0.0 plugin setup in my project and app gradle files.

Is their anything else that could cause an 
`Error logging in with Google. 12501 null`?

Here is the method that signs in:

```
startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
```

It successfully displays the login options, I can choose a Google account, but then I get the error.

Comment: Same problem here, my facebook one works fine, but google is having issues for some reason. It was working just fine for a long time and then randomly stopped with this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it's because I switched computers and had to add my debug.keystore fingerprint to firebase.

Steps:

1. keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
2. copy SHA1 (it has to be SHA1 because that's what they use for Oauth)
3. log into your firebase console -> project settings -> general -> android app
4. scroll down and add your SHA1 fingerprint to list of fingerprints
5. download new google-services.json and replace in your android studio project
6. delete app from phone and re-deploy

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification